# Type 'List<Widget?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using **connectivity_wrapper: ^1.0.6** in flutter application. while passing child to connectivity_wrapper it generates an error **type 'List<Widget?>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast** I have googled it but not able to find any solution. and also want to know the difference between List<Widget?> and 'List.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: appBarCustom(
    onBackTap: onBackTab,
    color: Colors.black,
    title: Strings.appName,
    textStyle: TextStyles.appBarBold,
    actions: [
      C0(),
    ],
  ),
  body: ConnectivityWidgetWrapper(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text("EX1"),
          onTap: () {

          },
        ),
        Divider(),
        ListTile(
          title: Text("EX@"),
          onTap: () {

          },
        ),
        Divider(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

**Error: type 'List<Widget?>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast**

Comment: You are giving a list that is null. It's the null safety question mark.

Comment: How we can handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an issue in [github](https://github.com/ajaykumargithub2114/connectivity_wrapper/issues/8#issue-850747326).so track that issue to solve your problem.
it's all about null safety.

Comment: it's my pleasure.

Comment: How we can handle it without removing "?" and adding child! to the connectivity_wrapper class?

Comment: you can disable null safety in your flutter.flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

Comment: or you can use another version of the package. and  look at docs here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Comment: Sure will read.